# Installation keeps complaining that Unicode library (mbstring) should be disabled, even though it seems it already is

Tags: 8, installation

I'm trying to install [Drupal 8.1.3](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/releases/8.1.3).
(Apache 2.4.7, PHP 5.5.37, Windows 7)

In the "Verify Requirements" step Drupal keeps complaining

> Unicode library -- Error -- Multibyte string input conversion in PHP
>   is active and must be disabled. Check the php.ini mbstring.http_input
>   setting. Please refer to the PHP mbstring documentation for more
>   information.

However, I already have the following in my php.ini

```
mbstring.http_input = pass
```

and the diagnostic output produced by a call to `phpinfo();` contains

```
zend.multibyte  | Off | Off
```

So I am not sure whether

1. I was unsuccessful in switching off the multibyte string input conversion,
2. I am looking at the wrong configuration files / settings, or
3. Something is wrong with Drupal's detection of these setting (see for instance [this discussion](https://www.drupal.org/node/2332295) on a failing detection).

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/mbstring.configuration.php#ini.mbstring.http-input

Drupal's code is checking it in core/lib/Drupal/Component/Utility/Unicode.php, but it won't even check if unless PHP version is < 5.6.0.  If you are using PHP 5.5.x here's the check:

```
  if (ini_get('mbstring.http_output') != 'pass') {
    static::$status = static::STATUS_ERROR;
    return 'mbstring.http_output';
  }
```

So I would double check the phpinfo via the Drupal interface at /admin/reports/status/php to make sure you are changing the config file that's used by PHP for Drupal.